# Does cflow generate a sound call graph from C programs?

Tags: c, linux, cflow

By "sound"ness, I mean that it has all the edges that are possible at runtime.

Comment: A static analyzer can't know which calls will be performed at the runtime. There can be some function pointers assigned with different functions based on the runtime information (different inputs?) and this will be totally evaded from this type of software.

Comment: `cflow` will not follow tables of function pointers, or function pointer variables.